# Python Neural Networks. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, elementwise-operations, relu

I am trying to add a ReLU activation function layer to my neural network. However when I try the following code I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried using:

```
class Relu(Activation):
    def __init__(self):
        def relu(x):
            return max(x, 0)

        def reluprime(x):
            return 1 if x > 0 else 0

        super().__init__(relu, reluprime)
```

I am very new to neural networks. Thank you

Comment: Always post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: It has nothing to do with neural networks - you can search that error and find loads of related results. You can't use `return 1 if x > 0 else 0` with arrays or related structures. `x` is not a single value

Comment: Have you checked the variable type of the variable that gives you the error?

Comment: Try replacing `return 1 if x > 0 else 0` with `return np.heaviside(x, 0)` (assuming you have `import numpy as np` at the beginning of your file)

Comment: Also replace `max(x, 0)` with `np.maximum(x, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `x` is a numpy array.

When dealing with numpy arrays, it is recommended to use numpy functions, which tend to act elementwise, rather than builtin python functions, which don't know what to do with a numpy array.

For instance, `max(x, 0)` makes sense if `x` is a number, but here `x` is an array, so what does it mean? How do you compare an array with 0?

Instead, use `np.maximum`, which will compare each element of the array with 0 and return an array.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.array([-12, 6, 0, 13])
>>> x
array([-12,   6,   0,  13])

>>> max(x, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> np.maximum(x, 0)
array([ 0,  6,  0, 13])
```

Likewise, instead of using an `1 if x > 0 else 0` expression which makes no sense if `x` is an array, use numpy function `heaviside`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.array([-12, 6, 0, 13])
>>> x
array([-12,   6,   0,  13])

>>> np.sign(x)
array([-1,  1,  0,  1])

>>> x > 0
array([False,  True, False,  True])

>>> 1 if x > 0 else 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> np.heaviside(x, 0)
array([0., 1., 0., 1.])
```

Relevant documentation:

- [numpy.maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html);
- [numpy.heaviside](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am really impressed by [Stef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74943436/5462372). If you need a simple answer then implement your class in the following way.

```
class Relu(Activation):
  def __init__(self):
    def relu(x):
        return np.maximum(x, 0)

    def reluprime(x):
        z = np.empty_like(x) 
        # create empty array similar in shape to x
        # use x to fill z.
        z[x<=0] = 0.
        z[x>0] = 1.
        return z

    super().__init__(relu, reluprime)
```

Relevant links:

[numpy.empty_like](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html)

[numpy.maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)

[numpy boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)